# Why leaflet marker still selected after cancel edition?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am starting with leaflet and leaflet.draw and I am having troubles at the moment I trie to change marker´s icon.

In this particular case I am trying to update all marker´s icon when I press cancel edition button. I can change the icons but all the markers still selected

Here is a fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/roywtaje/28/)

Steps to reproduce

1. Press edit button
2. Press cancel edit
3. You will see all the markers has changed their icons but at the same time all the markers still selected

Here is the code that I have to simulate undo icon change :

```
drawControl._toolbars.edit.disable =  function () {
  if (!this.enabled()) {
       /* If you need to do something right as the
       edit tool is enabled, do it here right
       before the return */
    return;
  }

  geojsonLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
     layer.setIcon(new  L.Icon.Default({}));
  });
  geojsonLayer2.eachLayer(function(layer) {
     layer.setIcon(new  L.Icon.Default({}));
  });

   this._activeMode.handler.revertLayers();

   L.Toolbar.prototype.disable.call(this);
};
```

Versions:
leaflet 1.3.4
leaflet.draw 1.0.3

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Your fiddle has errors. Please check it again.

Comment: Hello @kboul , I don´t see any error in the console on fiddler. Where are you seeing the error?

Comment: The map tiles are not rendered. `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` `5939.png`

Comment: I see what are you saying. Here is an edit fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/roywtaje/30/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a quick look at your code and I am not sure what causes this issue. However, I dived a bit into the editable marker code & style from the console and realized that once you hit the edit button the `.leaflet-edit-marker-selected` class is applied to each one of the drawn or rendered markers derived from `leaflet.draw.css line 9.`

So a possible workaround will be to remove `.leaflet-edit-marker-selected` class once 'draw:editstop' event is called:

```
map.on('draw:editstop',function(e) {
    $(".leaflet-pane img").removeClass("leaflet-edit-marker-selected");
    editing=false;
    map.closePopup();
});
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qsm6gbku/10/)

Comment: It could be a workaround .I am just realized something similar occur when I call setIcon() in another place. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/roywtaje/48/ . 1) Press edit, 2) Click a marker 3) Change the option of the combobox 4) The style 'leaflet-edit-marker-selected' just disappear from the edited marker

Comment: I reproduced what you said. Possibly leaflet.draw does not like the fact that you change the marker and apply your custom one on edit mode so the style is not applied anymore and that forces you to apply the default one manually every time you change the marker icon and implement your custom theme marker.

Comment: Yes, I think the same. I will wait some days to see if someone else answer the question, if not I am going to choose your answer. Thanks for your help!